# Is there anything wrong with using 'var undefined' to test for undefined

Tags: javascript

Is there anything wrong with this test for undefined?

```
var undefined;

if(x == undefined){
    //do something
}
```

or this:

```
function undefined(x){
    return typeof x == 'undefined';
}

if(undefined(x)){
    //do something
}
```

jsLint doesn't throws a reserverd word error, but the code still seems to work...

Comment: what's wrong with simply testing if (typeof(x) === 'undefined') { ... }

Comment: @Tim O Nothing, but 'x == undefined' or undefined(x) is much shorter. And I end up testing for undefined often. Just trying to make my life a bit easier...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Don't redefine `undefined`.

Other programmers expect `undefined` to always be `undefined`, not a function for function's sake.

People often use `typeof` operator to ensure a reference error is not thrown when used to test for variables that are `undefined`.

If anyone ever does this to you, you can use...

```
undefined = void 0;
```

... to revert it back.

Comment: Of course, some people go on the defensive and use the `void` operator to test: `if (a === void 0)`.

Comment: If you want your own function for this just name it `isUndefined()` or similar, to avoid clobbering the normal `undefined`.

Comment: To clarify, the `var undefined` part is fine, but making it into a function is not.

Answer (score 5):

As `undefined` isn't a [Javascript keyword](http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/JSKeywords.index.html), there's nothing wrong with it per se.

However, you're overriding a core variable that's used frequently for checking undefined variables in your second example to be a function. I'd shriek and ban that person as a committer if I saw that in anyone's code that I was reviewing.

Comment: Very good point. Thanks. Perhaps I'll just name the function isset

Comment: Not true, `function undefined(){}` throws an error since `undefined` is read only.

Comment: @adam: Not sure where you get that from (perhaps it's browser-dependent?): http://jsfiddle.net/9pK8N/. Runs just fine in Chrome.

Comment: chrome violates the spec here
The value of  undefined is  undefined (see 8.1). This property has  the attributes { [[Writable]]:  false, 
[[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }.

Comment: @adam: Good to know, however, it works in Chrome, FF4 and (surprisingly?) IE8.

Answer (score 1):

`undefined` is just a default property of the global object, which you can override/redefine. That's why you should always test for `undefined` using `typeof x == 'undefined'`, since the `typeof` operator cannot be redefined.

```
var undefined;

if(x == undefined){
    //do something
}
```

What happening here is that you're defining a new variable called *"undefined"*, which you don't assign a value and which hence gets the valued `undefined`. `x` is not defined either and also has a value of `undefined`. Hence both are equal. It's rather pointless though.

Comment: Yes. I understand why it works. I'm just trying to figure out why I shouldn't do it according to js lint

Comment: @Mark Redefining `undefined` as in the first example is obviously pointless. Redefining it as a function breaks code that checks against `x == undefined` (which you shouldn't do to begin with, but hey...).

Comment: I definitely wouldn't use them together, but I see your point. From the responses so far I can see that it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

`undefined` is not a reserved word in JavaScript (ECMA-262).
It is a named constant of type Undefined;

By declaring:

```
var undefined;
```

you declare variable with the same name in local scope.

So technically you can do this, just don't define something like this:

```
var undefined = 13;
```