# Handling undefined variables simple conditions in NodeJS

Tags: javascript

Given this function:

```
var test = function(param1, param2_maybe_not_set) {
  var my_object = {};
  // code here...
}
```

What's the best, in your opinion?

```
my_object.new_key = (param2_maybe_not_set === undefined) ? null : param2_maybe_not_set;
```

**OR**

```
my_object.new_key = (param2_maybe_not_set === void 0) ? null : param2_maybe_not_set;
```

**OR**

```
my_object.new_key = (typeof param2_maybe_not_set === 'undefined') ? null : param2_maybe_not_set;
```

Alternatively, would this shortened expression be correct?

```
my_object.new_key = param2_maybe_not_set || null;
```

All four methods work (in the NodeJS console at least). Also jsPerf doesn't show a big gap between any of these (http://jsperf.com/typeof-performance/8)

Which one should be used, as a *good practice*?

Comment: The last one is the most succinct and, I think, idiomatic in JavaScript. Alternatively, couldn't you just let the new property be undefined if the parameter is excluded?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are not strictly equivalent, but can often be used interchangeably. Here are the major differences between them:

- `x === undefined`: this performs a strict-equality comparison between the value and `undefined`, meaning that *only* a actual value of `undefined` will be `true`, whereas similar values like `null` or `0` will be false.

  In the case of a function call, this check does not differentiate between `f(a)` and `f(a, undefined)` (in fact, none of the examples will; to differentiate, you'll have to look at `arguments`).
- `x === void 0`: this uses the `void` keyword, which evaluates *any* expression and returns `undefined`. This was mostly done in the olden days to prevent surprises from people redefining the global `undefined` variable, but is not so useful nowadays ([ECMAScript 5 mandates that `undefined` be read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8783528/716118))
- `typeof x === 'undefined'`: this uses the `typeof` keyword, which has a unique ability - namely, that the [operand is *unevaluated*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). This means that something like `typeof foobarbaz` returns `'undefined'` even if no such variable `foobarbaz` exists *at all*. Contrast this with `foobarbaz === undefined`, which will throw a ReferenceError if the variable name has never been declared.
- `x || null`: this is the simplest and probably most readable alternative. The `||` operator is often used to "set defaults" on arguments, and can be chained like `x || y || z || null`.

  In most cases, this is the idiomatic technique used. **However**, note that `||` performs implicit conversions, which means that any "falsy" values will trigger the next value (meaning that it can't differentiate between `undefined`, `false`, `null`, `0`, `''`, and `NaN`). So, if your function expects to receive falsy values as arguments, it may be more prudent to explicitly check for `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

The option chosen to be an idiom in Javascript development to force a value for an unspecified argument is actually the last:

```
my_object.new_key = param2_maybe_not_set || null;
```

So this one should be preferrable since a lot of Javascript developers will immediately get its purpose.

Best.