# What happens if we set the value of undefined?

Tags: javascript, undefined

What does this line below do?

```
undefined = 'A value';
```

If it does not change the value of `undefined` then what happens behind the scenes?

Comment: the fact that it doesn't throw an error is worrisome

Comment: just tried it in the console and didn't even get an error, basically nothing happened at all https://gyazo.com/6703d9f7768e272c1aad7d3750b08ef1

Comment: @AshishMishra not true. It's just a property of the global context.

Comment: @JCOC611 It would only throw an error in strict mode.

Comment: @pointy yes uh right, actually they are the primitive data type so I just used keyword in place of that..

Comment: Similar question: [Javascript: How dangerous is it, really, to assume undefined is not overwritten?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783510/javascript-how-dangerous-is-it-really-to-assume-undefined-is-not-overwritten).

Comment: This reminds me of old versions of python (i.e. python<3) where `True`, `False` and `None` were just built-ins and not keywords, so that you could do `True = False` and stuff like that.

Comment: Here i've described what will happen if we set the value of undefined. https://codepen.io/grumpy/post/undefined-scope-in-javascript

Answer (score 53):

> `undefined` is a property of the global object, i.e. it is a variable in global scope. The initial value of `undefined` is the primitive value `undefined`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

So, it's just a variable, nothing special about it. Now, to answer your questions:

1. `undefined = 'A value';` attempts to assign a string `'A value'` to the global variable `undefined`
2. In older browsers the value changes, i.e. `undefined === 'A value'; // true`. In newer browsers under strict mode the operation results in an error.

You can test the following in a browser console (I'm using a modern browser here - Google Chrome):

```
undefined = true;
console.log(undefined); // undefined
// in older browsers like the older Internet Explorer it would have logged true
```

The value of `undefined` doesn't change in the above example. This is because (emphasis mine):

> In modern browsers (JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4+), undefined is a **non-configurable, non-writable property** per the ECMAScript 5 specification.

Under strict mode:

```
'use strict';
undefined = true; // VM358:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'undefined' of object
```

Comment: What about In newer browsers under "non-strict" mode ? it does not show any error. Does it do anything. cuz it does not change the value either

Comment: @Cgraphics In moder browsers under non-strict mode nothing happens. The value cannot be overwritten and there is no error... yet, but that might change in the future.

Comment: This is why you will sometimes see the `void` operator used - it evaluates its argument and then returns `undefined`, and because it is an operator it can't be assigned a value.  Thus you can always get `undefined` with the expression `void 0` or `void(0)` (operators don't require parens around arguments).

Answer (score 28):

Unlike things like `true`, `123` or `null`, `undefined` is not a [literal](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8). That means using the `undefined` [identifier](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6) is not a foolproof way to obtain the [undefined value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.9). Instead, can use the [`void` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.2), e.g. `void 0`.

By default, [`undefined`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.3) defined a property of the [global object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1), that is, global variable. Before ECMAScript 5, that property was writable, so

```
undefined = "A value";
```

replaced the value of `window.undefined`, assuming it was not shadowed by a local variable. Then if you used `"A value" === undefined`, you would get `true`. And `void 0 === undefined` would produce `false`.

ECMAScript 5 changed this behavior, and now the property is not writable nor configurable. Therefore, assignments to `undefined` will be ignored in non-strict mode, and will throw an exception is strict mode. Under the hood,

1. `undefined = "A value";` is a [Simple Assignment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1)
2. That uses [PutValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.2) to put the value `"A value"` in a reference with base the global object, referenced name `"undefined"`, and strict flag if the assignment is made in strict mode.
3. It calls the [[[Put]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.5) internal method of the global object, passing `"undefined"` as the property name, `"A value"` as the value, and the strict flag as the throw flag.
4. It calls the [[[DefineOwnProperty]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.9) internal method of the global object, passing `"undefined"`, the property descriptor `{[[Value]]: "A value"}`, and the throw flag as arguments.
5. It rejects, that is, throws a TypeError exception if the throw flag is true, otherwise returns false.

However, you are still able to declare local `undefined` variables:

```
(function() {
  var undefined = "A value";
  alert(undefined); // "A value";
})();
```

Comment: "However, you are still able to declare local undefined variables:" - Good point!

Comment: Once upon a time, `NaN` was also a global variable that could be written to

Answer (score 3):

I've made a little POC with and without `strict mode`.

The effect is that, if you're not using `strict mode` everything goes fine. If you're using `strict mode` you'll have a nice:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'undefined'

Now let's get to the POC:

```
"use strict"
var c;

if (c === undefined) {
  console.log("nothing happened")
}

undefined = "goofy"

c = "goofy"

if (c === undefined) {
  console.log("c is 'goofy' and it's equal to undefined.. gosh.. we broke js")
}
```

Now, as I said, with strict mode you obtain a `TypeError` while removing the `"use strict"` the script goes fine and the output is simply `nothing happened`.

I've found [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783510/javascript-how-dangerous-is-it-really-to-assume-undefined-is-not-overwritten) that could be useful if you want to know more

*NOTE*: I've tested this code using `Node.js`.

Comment: Why node.js? I thought it was for server side

Comment: @Cgraphics node.js uses V8 – the same JavaScript engine as Google Chrome, so it's basically the same rules, but different APIs (browsers have `window`, `querySelector` etc., node has `global`, `fs.write`, etc.).

Comment: Since Node.js it's build over V8 (The Google Chrome engine) which uses ES6 it seemed the fastest way to create the POC. :)

Answer (score 0):

in addition to [Oriol answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519946/what-happens-if-we-set-the-value-of-undefined/36520202#36520202)

you can also have a block-level undefined variable

```
{  
    let emptyVar;
    // console.log(emptyVar === undefined); // Cannot access 'undefined' before initialization
    const undefined = "some value";
    console.log(undefined);
    console.log(void 0); // primitive undefined
}
```