# javascript: Is is possible to assign a value to 'undefined'? (a question from You-Dont-know JS)

Tags: javascript, undefined

Reading You-dont-know-Js at this chapter: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/ch3.md

there's a code snippet:

```js
undefined = true; // setting a land-mine for other code! avoid!

(function IIFE( undefined ){

 var a;
 if (a === undefined) {
  console.log( "Undefined is safe here!" );
 }

})();
```

as for the immediately executed function, I know that the argument is undefined, a is also undefined, thus a===undefined.

my question is that, how is it possible to assign a value to undefined?
 As I understand, undefined is a primitive type in js, then what is the meaning of undefined = true;?

Additionally, to test my understanding, I changed this code a little:

```js
undefined = 5; // set undefined to an integer? how can it be?

(function IIFE( undefined ){

 var a;
 if (a === undefined) {
  console.log( "Undefined is safe here!" );
 }

})(undefined);  //still execute console.log function
```

and the result remains same

Comment: AT one point yes, but browsers/engines fixed it

Comment: Try the second snippet but supply any other value to the IIFE `(function(undefined) {})(42)`

Comment: @epascarello it's still a potential problem but more contained. You can have a parameter called `undefined` and pass in a value to it. This does shadow the actual `undefined`.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519946/what-happens-if-we-set-the-value-of-undefined

Comment: @AkashSrivastav good thread. thanks

Comment: If you want to define the undefined you must first undefine the defined, from the book of the chicken and an egg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how is it possible to assign a value to undefined? As I understand, undefined is a primitive type in js, then what is the meaning of undefined = true;?

You are right, `undefined` is a primitive type, but it isn't a [*literal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)).

When you access `undefined`, you are accessing a property in the global object.

Before ES5, this property was writable, and it could be overridden.

But since ES5, it [was defined as *not writable*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.3), and now it cannot be changed.

Not being a literal like [`null`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#prod-NullLiteral), [`true` or `false`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-boolean-literals), makes possible to use `undefined` as a binding name for a variable, a parameter on a function or the name of a function, but not in the global scope. It will clash with the built-in `undefined`.

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';  
  const undefined = 'some value';  
  console.log(undefined); // "some value"  
})();
```

Comment: so for the second code snippet, when "undefined = 5", actually undefined is not assigned to 5(because it is not writable) ?

Comment: @LeonloveKaren in strict mode, ES5+, `"use strict"; undefined = 5;` throws a TypeError. In non strict, it just silently does nothing.

Comment: "*makes it possible to use undefined as a binding name for a variable or function.*" just to clarify, this cannot be done in global scope, since it's still clashing with the `window` property, but you can have `var undefined` in function scope, for example.

Comment: @ASDFGerte If I was the code inventor, I would prefer throw error at any situation, no matter strict mode is.

Comment: @VLAZ, added clarification and example, tks!

Comment: JS has a lot, and i mean a LOT of legacy issues. Writing code in non-strict is imho ill advised anyways. While you are at "weird JS things in a browser", you can try `typeof document.all === "undefined" && document.all !== undefined`

Comment: @ASDFGerte, yes, the assignment it will fail, and it will crash under strict mode. Meaning that if you are using ES6 modules, which are strict by default, it will just crash.

Comment: @ASDFGerte my favourite legacy issue is `typeof null === "object"`.