# undefined when declared as a variable name throws error in browser but runs successfully when runs in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

I tried to execute following lines of code on Nodejs and chrome browser.
In nodejs, it executed successfully But on chrome browser, it throws an error.

```
const undefined = 1;
console.log(undefined); 
// Nodejs: prints 1
//chrome browser: VM359:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'undefined' has already been declared
```

If undefined is already declared as a value, don't you guys think `undefined` is behaving a variable in nodejs ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519946/what-happens-if-we-set-the-value-of-undefined for an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not override undefined according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/7173833/1331578 . It might work on node where no global object will be used. But in general it is just not writable name.