# Compare javascript objects with `undefined` attributes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

How should lodash/underscore `.isEqual(o1,o2)` or `assert.deepEqual(o1,o2)` handle objects with `undefined` values?  I'd like a deepEquals that returns true in a case like this:

```
 var left = {a: true, b: undefined};
 var right = {a: true};
 assert(_.isEqual(left, right))   // returns false
```

Alternatively, is there a way to test whether attribute `b` is defined as `undefined` versus simply not being defined?

```
 typeof left.b //  "undefined"
 typeof right.b // "undefined

 left.b === undefined  // true
 right.b === undefined // true
```

Right now i'm using this for expedience, but suspect it will yield false negatives:

```
var isEqual = function(o1, o2) { return JSON.stringify(o1) === JSON.stringify(o2)}
```

[How to check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Alternatively, is there a way to test whether attribute b is defined as undefined versus simply not being defined?

Yes, there are lots of ways to distinguish these cases.

```
"b" in left; // true
"b" in right; // false

left.hasOwnProperty("b"); // true
right.hasOwnProperty("b"); // false

left.propertyIsEnumerable('b'); // true
right.propertyIsEnumerable('b'); // false

Object.keys(left).includes("b"); // true
Object.keys(right).includes("b"); // false

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(left).includes("b"); // true
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(right).includes("b"); // false

Reflect.ownKeys(left).includes("b"); // true
Reflect.ownKeys(right).includes("b"); // false

!!Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(left, 'b'); // true
!!Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(right, 'b'); // false

!!Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(left, 'b'); // true
!!Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(right, 'b'); // false

!!(o => {for(var p in o) if(p==='b') return 1; return 0;})(left); // true
!!(o => {for(var p in o) if(p==='b') return 1; return 0;})(right); // false
```

Looking at the annotated source, I think this will be enough:

```
_.myEqual = function(a,b) {
  var keys = _.keys;
  _.keys = function(obj) { /* Hijack _.keys to filter out undefined properties */
    return _.filter(keys(obj), function(key){ return obj[key] !== void 0; });
  };
  var ret = _.isEqual(a,b); /* Call usual comparator, will use modified _.keys */
  _.keys = keys; /* Restore usual _.keys */
  return ret;
}
```

```js
_.myEqual = function(a,b) {
  var keys = _.keys;
  _.keys = function(obj) {
    return _.filter(keys(obj), key => obj[key] !== void 0);
  };
  var ret = _.isEqual(a,b);
  _.keys = keys;
  return ret;
}
console.log(_.myEqual({a: true, b: undefined}, {a: true})); // true
console.log(_.myEqual({a: true, b: true}, {a: true})); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jashkenas/underscore/master/underscore.js"></script>
```

Comment: For completeness, you could add `propertyIsEnumerable`,

Answer (score 2):

this will strip out undefined and preserve the other desirable properties of `assert.deepEqual` and `_.isEqual` like insensitivity to attribute order:

`assert.jsonEqual = function(a, b) {
    return deepEqual(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)), JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b)))
}`

Answer (score 0):

The reason `left` is not equal to `right` is because `b` is a property on left, even though it's undefined.

To check to see if the property exists on an object, even if it's undefined (as in your example with left) use the **in** operator:

```
"b" in left; // true
"b" in right; // false
```

Javascript **in** operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

---

A quick function to check to see if a property exists and is undefined:

```
function propertyExistsAndIsUndefined(object, property) {
    return property in object && typeof object[property] === "undefined";
}
```

Comment: Why not just `property in object && object[property] === undefined`?

Comment: `undefined` could be overwritten by someone else. Because `undefined` is just a property of the global object whose value is undefined, you could write `undefined = true` and now `object[property] === undefined` will return false. (Modern browsers do not allow `undefined` to be unwritable, but still.) `undefined` is also not a reserved word, so I suppose you could also make a local variable named `undefined`. The result of `typeof` should never change, making it more reliable. If it does, then there are probably larger problems on your hands.

Comment: `object[property] === void 0` will also work because the `void` operator always evaluates to undefined.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783510/how-dangerous-is-it-in-javascript-really-to-assume-undefined-is-not-overwritte.