# Is it possible to force the boolean true to equal false in javascript?

Tags: javascript, boolean

Is there a way to make `true = false`. When I try that, it obviously returns an invalid left-hand assignment. This is something that I have been curious about for a while, and I would appreciate an answer. I have tried a lot of things, but I haven't figured out how to do it. Here's some things that I've tried so far:

```js
true = false;
var true = false;
let true = false;
const true = false;
Boolean(true) = false;
true = !true;
var true = !true;
let true = !true;
const true = !true;
Boolean(true) = !true;
```

Comment: It appears that `true` and `false` are "reserved words".

Comment: @GetSet, If you make that an answer, I will select it.

Comment: Short answer is no....They are immutable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because true and false are reserved keywords, there's no way to assign to them. Even if you did `window.true = false`, true would still be true.

This isn't necessarily the case with all primitives. in es4 you were allowed to reassign `undefined` to be whatever you want it to be. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783510/how-dangerous-is-it-in-javascript-really-to-assume-undefined-is-not-overwritte) related discussion - it talks about weather or not to bother safe-guarding against it, but it you could find it informative)

Comment: `window.true` doesn't exist

Comment: In node, window isn't a thing, you would do global.true instead. And yes, true isn't a property on either of those, but usually when you set a property on it, e.g. window.x = 2, then using x, e.g. x + 3, would work. I used it as an example, because in older versions of javascript you could do `window.undefined = 2`, but this is now how true/false behave.