# Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

I am declaring the following variables using TypeScript:

```
const BOT_PREFIX: string = process.env.PREFIX;
const BOT_TOKEN: string = process.env.TOKEN;
```

I get the following error:

> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

I can fix it by changing the data type to `any`, but i don't want to do that.

Comment: Well, what _if_ the variable is undefined? This will occur if that environment variable wasn't set for your process. What should `BOT_PREFIX` or `BOT_TOKEN` be then?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Node's `process.env` has the following type definition (from [this declaration file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d7b9ab1d13d2cf9fae5bb6d6a0c0e1c549ea7679/types/node/process.d.ts#L95) which uses a type defined [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d7b9ab1d13d2cf9fae5bb6d6a0c0e1c549ea7679/types/node/globals.d.ts#L646-L648)):

```
interface ProcessEnv {
    [key: string]: string | undefined
}
```

So, as far as TypeScript's compiler is concerned, any property you access under `process.env` will be of type `string | undefined`.  That's a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), meaning that `process.env.RANDOMKEY` (for example) will either be a `string` or it will be `undefined`. Generally speaking this is the right type; the compiler has no idea which environment variables are actually set.

And so this is a problem:

```
const BOT_PREFIX: string = process.env.PREFIX // error!
```

and the compiler warns you that `process.env.PREFIX` might be `undefined`, so it's not safe to treat it as a `string`.

The way to deal with this depends on whether you want convenience or type safety, and what you want to see happen if your assumptions about `process.env.PREFIX` and `process.env.TOKEN` are incorrect.

---

For pure convenience, you probably can't beat the [non-null assertion operator (`!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
const BOT_PREFIX: string = process.env.PREFIX!; // okay
const BOT_TOKEN: string = process.env.TOKEN!; // okay
```

Here you are just *telling* the compiler that, even though it cannot verify this, you are sure `process.env.PREFIX` and `process.env.TOKEN` will be defined.  This essentially just suppresses the compiler warning; it's still doing the same thing at runtime as your original code.  And that means if you turn out to be wrong about your assertion, then you might run into problems at runtime that the compiler can't help you with:

```
BOT_PREFIX.toUpperCase(); // runtime error if BOT_PREFIX is undefined after all
```

So be careful.

---

On the other hand, you can try to make the code safer by handling the situation in which the environment variables you expect are not set.  For example:

```
function getEnvVar(v: string): string {
    const ret = process.env[v];
    if (ret === undefined) {
        throw new Error("process.env." + v + " is undefined!");
    }
    return ret;
}

const BOT_PREFIX: string = getEnvVar("PREFIX");
const BOT_TOKEN: string = getEnvVar("TOKEN");
```

Here we've written a function called `getEnvVar()` which takes the name of the environment variable and returns its value, as long as that value is a `string`. If the environment variable is not defined, then a runtime error will be thrown.  TypeScript understands via [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) that the return type of `getEnvVar()` is `string` (and not `string | undefined`; the `undefined` possibility has been eliminated by the `throw` statement), and so you can safely assign the returned value to a variable of type `string`.

This code is obviously less convenient since it requires extra runtime code, but now instead of possibly lying to the compiler and having bizarre runtime behavior, you will get some immediate feedback at runtime if your assumptions are invalid.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=37&pln=5&pc=1#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)

Comment: Wouldn't `typeof ret === "undefined"` be clearer as just `ret === undefined`?

Comment: maybe? I guess the days when the variable named `undefined` could be reassigned are [long gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783510/how-dangerous-is-it-in-javascript-really-to-assume-undefined-is-not-overwritte) but for some reason I always write `typeof x === "undefined"` to be "safe".  I'll change it

Comment: **Thanks very much really!!**

Answer (score 4):

Since those are environment variables which makes it pretty sure that those value won't be empty or undefined.

You may use [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

should look like this:

```
const BOT_PREFIX: string = process.env.PREFIX!;
const BOT_TOKEN: string = process.env.TOKEN!;
```

Just make sure your environment variables are filled.

you can also do this:

```
const BOT_PREFIX: string = process.env.PREFIX || '';
const BOT_TOKEN: string = process.env.TOKEN || '';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ES6 template literals

```
const BOT_PREFIX: string = `${process.env.PREFIX}`;
const BOT_TOKEN: string = `${process.env.TOKEN}`;
```